# Table won't be displayed with head() in R Notebook

Tags: r, markdown, rnotebook

Code entered into R Notedbook:

**Code:**

```
---
title: "test"
output: html_notebook
---
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir=WORKING.DIRECTORY)
```

```
summary(cars)
```

```
head(cars)
```

**Output:**
[image: Output produced by code above]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! According to your post, it looks like you're a new contributor. These links are great resources: [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://Hi%20and%20welcome%20to%20StackOverflow!%20According%20to%20your%20post,%20it%20looks%20like%20you're%20a%20new%20contributor.%20Please%20consider%20reviewing%20the%20following%20links:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and [FAQ Index for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getwd()` instead of WORKING.DIRECTORY.

````
``` r{r setup, include=FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir=getwd())

```
````

**Generate new code chunk:**

The keyboard shortcut to do this is ***Ctrl + Alt + I (OS X: Cmd + Option + I)***

````
```{r}

summary(cars)
head(cars)

```
````

**Output:**

```
#>      speed           dist       
#>  Min.   : 4.0   Min.   :  2.00  
#>  1st Qu.:12.0   1st Qu.: 26.00  
#>  Median :15.0   Median : 36.00  
#>  Mean   :15.4   Mean   : 42.98  
#>  3rd Qu.:19.0   3rd Qu.: 56.00  
#>  Max.   :25.0   Max.   :120.00


#>   speed dist
#> 1     4    2
#> 2     4   10
#> 3     7    4
#> 4     7   22
#> 5     8   16
#> 6     9   10
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you actually run the code chunks you want to see displayed and
save the file:

[image]

---

I've also set `root.dir` to the result of `getwd()`. This doesn't change the result as far as displaying the tables, but here is the whole file for reference:

```
---
title: "test"
output: html_notebook
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: inline
---
```

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir=getwd())
```
````

````
```{r}
summary(cars)
head(cars)
```
````